# form <input> not spanning 100% width of form

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When adding form-group with an input, the input field will not go to 100% width of the form group which is already the width of the card.

I've tried adding styles for width directly to the parent element and to the input element itself.

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="card d-flex justify-content-center" style="background-color:dodgerblue; height:60vh; width:40vw; border-radius:20px">
        <div class="card-body ml-4 mt-3 text-center">

                <div class="row ml-4">
                    <div class="form-group mr-5" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; vertical-align: middle;">
                        <label for="cardNumber">Card number</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" name="cardNumber" placeholder="Your card number" class="form-control" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <a class="btn btn-primary text-center mt-3" href="">Continue</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see what I mean in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d1vyzbLg/) window, the input will not span 100% width of the card.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add bootstrap cdn/url. Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yasinuddowla/wfhj29g3/)

```
 <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">
   <div class="card d-flex justify-content-center" style="background-color:dodgerblue; height:60vh; width:40vw; border-radius:20px">
     <div class="card-body ml-4 mt-3 text-center">

       <div class="row ml-4" >
         <div class="form-group mr-5" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; vertical-align: middle;">
           <label for="cardNumber">Card number</label>
           <div class="input-group">
             <input type="text" name="cardNumber" placeholder="Your card number" class="form-control" required>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah ive got that in my project already mate, Thank you though

Comment: Yeah man, i posted the answer below. it was an extremely silly thing i missed before posting. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out and it was an extremely basic thing that i missed.

I removed the "max-width" of the inputs that comes in the site.css file by default.

thanks for the response!